# Is anyone working on an updated subdivision modifier for threejs post r.60?

Tags: three.js

Four sided faces are a staple of 3d animation tools.  I realize that the use of face3 is helpful for real time rendering but for my purposes quad subdivision is important.  Is there perhaps a way to 'tag' sets of triangles so they know they're part of a quad?  Is anyone working on making an updated subdivision modifier?

I just recently updated my library, so I'm a little late to the game with this new feature.  I'm also a fairly new programmer.  How hard would it be to 'patch' threejs with face4s?

thanks!

Comment: Subdivision modifier works in three.js r.66. It is face3-based. There are a few known limitations, which are listed in the comments in the source code.